# Stop matching after first occurence (single line)

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

How could I just match the first anchor tag and not all of them until the last one? Basically all of this: "<a...>...</a>" without the other ones? Would I need to sub the string before matching?

[image]

Here's what I got:
https://regex101.com/r/hXh2JI/1

Thank you!

Comment: why is this tagged Lua? I don't see any Lua code nor does Lua have regular expressions

Comment: Writing it in lua.

Comment: then you should not tag other languages and provide some on attempt in Lua otherwise you're wasting peoples' time by having them write irrelevant answers.#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/Sz2Msb/1) regex does what you're asking for. Add the `global` and `multi line` regex flags to capture all cases of  `<a> ... </a>`.

Regex looks like this:

```
(<a>.*<\/a>)
```

Comment: That's not working in lua for some reason. I think it's single line only. Using this compiler https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php

Comment: Can't help with Lua unfortunately. The regex I posted works for me on your own test case from your link, e.g. it matches only the first `<a>` tag and its content.

Comment: Lua does not support regex, only specific patterns that are not regular expressions.